# Selenium does not click on radio button on pop up

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java

[image]

1. On form, there is one binocular.
2. On click on binocular, pop up opens.
3. **There are radio buttons on pop up**. **I need to click on radio buttons, it's failing**.

**I have tried below code but it shows error**

```java
findElement(By.id("clCategory_binacular")).click();
WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(d,10);
WebElement ele=wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[@id='idCommonGridTableclCategory_binacularGridContainer']/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]/div/label")));
Actions builder =new Actions(d);
builder.moveToElement(ele).click().build();
```

**Error:**

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: By.xpath: //*[@id='idCommonGridTableclCategory_binacularGridContainer']/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]/div/label (tried for 10 second(s) with 500 MILLISECONDS interval)
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
```

**Below is html code:**

```html
<tbody>
  <tr class="jqgfirstrow" role="row" style="height:auto">
    <td role="gridcell" style="height:0px;width:150px;display:none;">
    </td>
    <td role="gridcell" style=
        "height:0px;width:150px;display:none;">
    </td>
    <td role="gridcell" style="height: 0px; width: 192px;">
    </td>
    <td role="gridcell" style="height: 0px; width: 957px;">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr role="row"
      id="4864.33645.61824.39547" tabindex="0" class="ui-widget-content jqgrow ui-row-ltr ui-state-highlight" aria-selected="true">
    <td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" 
        aria-describedby="idCommonGridTableclCategory_binacularGridContainer_id">4864.33645.61824.39547
    </td>
    <td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" aria-describedby=
        "idCommonGridTableclCategory_binacularGridContainer_cellData">{"id":"4864.33645.61824.39547","key":"clCategory","forID":"clCategory","value":"Legal - General","label":"Legal - 
      General","name":"C2-1","categoryType":"General","type":"LEXClauseCategory"}
    </td>
    <td role="gridcell" style="" class="selectToInsertCol" aria-describedby=
        "idCommonGridTableclCategory_binacularGridContainer_">
      <div class="radioInlineMargin toggle-primary toggle-inline toggle toggle-root">
        <input type="radio" class="selectToInsertTemplate"
               name="selectToInsertTemplate" id="selectCp4864336456182439547" value="">
        <label class="control-label" for="selectCp4864336456182439547"></label>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td role="gridcell" style=
        "text-align:left;" aria-describedby="idCommonGridTableclCategory_binacularGridContainer_title">Legal - General
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr role="row" id="4864.33645.61824.40762" tabindex="-1" class=
      "ui-widget-content jqgrow ui-row-ltr">
    <td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" aria-describedby="idCommonGridTableclCategory_binacularGridContainer_id">4864.33645.61824.40762
    </td>
    <td
        role="gridcell" style="display:none;" aria-describedby="idCommonGridTableclCategory_binacularGridContainer_cellData">
      {"id":"4864.33645.61824.40762","key":"clCategory","forID":"clCategory","value":"Legal - Standardized Deviations","label":"Legal - Standardized 
      Deviations","name":"C2-2","categoryType":"Deviation","type":"LEXClauseCategory"}
    </td>
    <td role="gridcell" style="" class="selectToInsertCol" aria-describedby=
        "idCommonGridTableclCategory_binacularGridContainer_">
      <div class="radioInlineMargin toggle-primary toggle-inline toggle toggle-root">
        <input type="radio" class="selectToInsertTemplate"
               name="selectToInsertTemplate" id="selectCp4864336456182440762" value="">
        <label class="control-label" for="selectCp4864336456182440762"></label>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td role="gridcell" style=
        "text-align:left;" aria-describedby="idCommonGridTableclCategory_binacularGridContainer_title">Legal - Standardized Deviations
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr role="row" id="4864.33645.61824.36371" 
      tabindex="-1" class="ui-widget-content jqgrow ui-row-ltr">
    <td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" aria-describedby="idCommonGridTableclCategory_binacularGridContainer_id">
      4864.33645.61824.36371
    </td>
    <td role="gridcell" style="display:none;" aria-describedby="idCommonGridTableclCategory_binacularGridContainer_cellData">
      {"id":"4864.33645.61824.36371","key":"clCategory","forID":"clCategory","value":"Pricing and Negotiation - Standardized Deviations","label":"Pricing and Negotiation - Standardized 
      Deviations","name":"C1-2","categoryType":"Deviation","type":"LEXClauseCategory"}
    </td>
    <td role="gridcell" style="" class="selectToInsertCol" aria-describedby=
        "idCommonGridTableclCategory_binacularGridContainer_">
      <div class="radioInlineMargin toggle-primary toggle-inline toggle toggle-root">
        <input type="radio" class="selectToInsertTemplate"
               name="selectToInsertTemplate" id="selectCp4864336456182436371" value="">
        <label class="control-label" for="selectCp4864336456182436371"></label>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td role="gridcell" style=
        "text-align:left;" aria-describedby="idCommonGridTableclCategory_binacularGridContainer_title">Pricing and Negotiation - Standardized Deviations
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the below code

```
WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver,10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("div>label[class='control-label']"))).click();
```

OR can use javascriptExecutor

```
WebElement radio = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div>label[class='control-label']"));

JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Comment: By using java script executor its able to select radio button .That's positive thing! But as soon as I click Proceed (run next step -submit pop up) it shows me error message to select radio button. Now if I manually select radio button & click submit it works

Comment: Below code worked perfectly :Js executor & xpath combination!                                                                
WebElement radio = d.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='4864.33645.61824.39547']/td[3]/div/label"));
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)d;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", radio);